# Hive: "FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask null" when dropped large amount of partitions

Tags: hive

I am trying to drop 6024 partitions from a hive table which contains 630127 partitions in total(The hive version was 2.3.6). But after I run:

> alter table [table_name] drop if exists partition (dt = '${hiveconf:dt}');

waited around 10 seconds, then the following error happened:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask null

I also tried to run hive in debug mode, here are some logs:

> 2022-01-03T00:06:31,801 WARN  [26c37106-11e1-497d-8ffe-7519750b8ec1 main([])]: metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient (RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:invoke(218)) - MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect (1 of 1) after 1s. getTable
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.send_get_table_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1561) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1553) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1350) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:127) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2336) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1279) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.getTable(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:1713) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.getTable(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:1693) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeAlterTableDropParts(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:2741) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:287) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:258) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:512) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar:?]
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:159) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> ... 41 more
> 2022-01-03T00:06:32,801 WARN  [26c37106-11e1-497d-8ffe-7519750b8ec1 main([])]: transport.TIOStreamTransport (TIOStreamTransport.java:close(112)) - Error closing output stream.
> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.close(TIOStreamTransport.java:110) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.close(TSocket.java:235) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.close(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:563) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.reconnect(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:335) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:163) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:493) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar:?]
> 2022-01-03T00:06:31,801 WARN  [26c37106-11e1-497d-8ffe-7519750b8ec1 main([])]: metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient (RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:invoke(218)) - MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect (1 of 1) after 1s. getTable
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.send_get_table_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1561) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1553) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1350) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:127) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2336) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1279) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.getTable(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:1713) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.getTable(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:1693) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeAlterTableDropParts(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:2741) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:287) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:258) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:512) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) ~[hive-cli-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar:?]
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.5-amzn-6.jar:?]
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:159) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> ... 41 more
> 2022-01-03T00:06:32,801 WARN  [26c37106-11e1-497d-8ffe-7519750b8ec1 main([])]: transport.TIOStreamTransport (TIOStreamTransport.java:close(112)) - Error closing output stream.
> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.close(TIOStreamTransport.java:110) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.close(TSocket.java:235) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.close(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:563) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.reconnect(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:335) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:163) ~[hive-exec-2.3.6-amzn-2.jar:2.3.6-amzn-2]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getTable(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]

Can anyone help me on that? Any hint will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you pls try dropping just one partition and see if its throwing same error.

Comment: tried that, few partitions worked

Comment: Got it. I think may be `${hiveconf:dt}` is calculated as null. can you pls check that first? And if you can try hardcoding it than a variable?

Comment: I tried hardcoding it with `2021-09-30` (which it should be), but still same error.

Comment: Can you pls post complete qry here with hard ode 2021 09 30?

Comment: yes, sure. here it is:

```
hive> alter table [table_name] drop if exists partition (dt = '2021-09-30');

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. null
```

Comment: According to debug code, the connection of hive client lost to hive metastore. The Partition count is quite high for a table in Hive. If you can try to increase the hive metastore Xmx (heap) value before attempting to drop partitions.

Comment: Hi, @HakkiBuyukcengiz
I increased the metastore Xmx to 12288m (I think it's large enough). but the error still there. FYI, here are part of the options:
`/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xmx12288m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled ...... org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /home/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-service-0.13.1-amzn-3.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore`

Comment: What is the underlying metastore database of the hive metastore? Is it accessible?

Comment: Hi, @HakkiBuyukcengiz
it's MySql, and yes it's accessible.

Comment: I can suggest that: 1- check the hivemetastore logs at the time just when you issue the query. 2- Try to increase "hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout".